# how to give proper alignment for div

Tags: html, css

here is my code, I need to display a page with 3 images one is on the left and other two on the right side but all images are displaying in the same line, they are not displaying in order that I

1. List item

   have given. please help me in solving these.

```css
.leftAlign {
    float: left;
}
.rightAlign {
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;
}
.rightOrder{
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;
}
.primary-button {
    background-color: #109bd5;
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div class="about-content">
  <h4 mat-dialog-title>Hello World</h4>
    <div mat-dialog-content>
      <div class='leftAlign'>
        <h4>IMAGE1</h4>
        <img src="assets/images/image1.png">
      </div>
      <div class='rightAlign'>
        <h4>IMAGE2</h4>
        <img src="assets/images/image2.png">
      </div>
      <div class='rightOrder'>
        <h4>ICON</h4>
        <img src="assets/images/icon_img.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div mat-dialog-actions align="end">
      <button mat-button mat-dialog-close class="mat-button               primary-button">close
      </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you check the grid system in bootstrap that will help you in responsive design also.

Comment: That's the way [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) works. Simple solution: change the order in your HTML. Good solution: switch to something like a flexbox-based layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between;">
          <div>
            <!-- This will be left aligned -->
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=1" alt="image 1">
          </div>
          <div>
            <!-- This will be right aligned -->
           <div>
             <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=2" alt="image 2">
           </div>
           <div>
             <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=3" alt="image 3">
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Please have look at this, if you are using Bootstrap, I will recommend using it instead of giving inline style.

Comment: actually, the images should not display side by side. they should be one by one which is in the right side

Comment: Did you mean right side images should be displayed as one beneath the another?